# Allowing SVG uploads in media uploader without plug-in

Tags: functions, uploads, content, svg

I have previously managed to utilise this block of code within my functions.php file to enable and create thumbnails for SVGs that are uploaded to my site:

```
// ALLOW SVG
    function add_file_types_to_uploads($file_types){
        $new_filetypes = array();
        $new_filetypes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml';
        $file_types = array_merge($file_types, $new_filetypes );
        return $file_types;
    }
    add_action('upload_mimes', 'add_file_types_to_uploads');

    function common_svg_media_thumbnails($response, $attachment, $meta){
        if($response['type'] === 'image' && $response['subtype'] === 'svg+xml' && class_exists('SimpleXMLElement'))
        {
            try {
                $path = get_attached_file($attachment->ID);
                if(@file_exists($path))
                {
                    $svg = new SimpleXMLElement(@file_get_contents($path));
                    $src = $response['url'];
                    $width = (int) $svg['width'];
                    $height = (int) $svg['height'];

                    //media gallery
                    $response['image'] = compact( 'src', 'width', 'height' );
                    $response['thumb'] = compact( 'src', 'width', 'height' );

                    //media single
                    $response['sizes']['full'] = array(
                        'height'        => $height,
                        'width'         => $width,
                        'url'           => $src,
                        'orientation'   => $height > $width ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'
                    );
                }
            }
            catch(Exception $e){}
        }

        return $response;
    }
    add_filter('wp_prepare_attachment_for_js', 'common_svg_media_thumbnails', 10, 3);
// END ALLOW SVG
```

I am now trying to copy this code over to a new site but I still receive the error:

```
"logo.svg” has failed to upload.
Sorry, this file type is not permitted for security reasons.
```

This site is located within a subdirectory of a non-WordPress website, like:

```
www.example.co.uk/SITE_DIRECTORY/wp-content/themes/THEME_NAME/functions.php
```

Am I missing a step to get this working?

~ Please do not reference plug-ins.

~ Please help me get this code snippet that has been previously proven to work on a different site; working on this new site.

Thanks, Jason.

Comment: Keep in mind that the code in this question is dangerous and will allow the upload of malicious and compromised SVG's. SVG's are not images, they're documents, and can contain arbitrary HTML and javascript. A plugin such as SafeSVG will sanitise SVGs on upload so that they can be safely added to a site. Keep in mind that plugin recommendations are offtopic on this site though, hence why I leave this as a comment. Perhaps you can provide some context for why? That would help people understand rather than just a blanket ban that invites questions, or, make alternatives clearer

Comment: Also, you should remove the `@` on the `file_exists`, `@` does not fix issues, it simply silences them, the problem still happens, all it does is redirect the error message to trash.

Comment: Thank you for highlighting that, that is enough of a reason to me to switch to using a plug-in. Appreciate the help!

Comment: The plugin is mostly a wrapper around a library. For this Q, I suspect the problem is the mimetype, but I'm unsure of the exact specifics to write an answer

Comment: Same thinking here, also not sure how though.

Answer (score 5):

```
function cc_mime_types($mimes) {
  $mimes['svg'] = 'image/svg+xml'; 
  return $mimes;
}
add_filter('upload_mimes', 'cc_mime_types');
```

add in  functions.php  in  your active theme

```
define('ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true);
```

add in wp-config.php

Comment: To be clear, this is two answers, you don't need to do both. If you allow unfiltered uploads, you are effectively turning off the file type validation.

Comment: Correct! Filter is enough and i think that this is best option.